# How come the page gives 404 but return contents

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Following is my php file with wordpress

```
<?php
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['userpass'];

$results = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT *
        FROM wp_users 
        WHERE user_login = %s
    ",
    $name
),ARRAY_N,0);

$checked = wp_check_password($pass, $results[2]);

if ($checked) {
    echo 'y';
} else {
    echo 'n';
}
?>
```

The main purpose of this page is to verify username and password. It works perfectly fine, when username/password is correct, show 'y', otherwise show 'n'.

The weird thing is, no matter I sent the post method via html form or others, although it returns either y or n, the status code is always 404.

How come it returns contents with a 404. I didn't manipulate any status code in this php.

I know I should create my own template. My question is not that, but how come an http response will be both 404 and with replied contents.

Comment: visit [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) to read how to create custom template. After creating template assign template to your page.

Comment: @Nisarg All right. I will do so. My question is why a page can return 404 and its contents together.

Comment: What content you have included in `wp-blog-header.php` ?

Comment: @Nisarg I didn't add anything special to `wp-blog-header.php`. It is the one when I installed WP.

Comment: add `wp-config.php` file instead of `wp-blog-header.php` and try it and define `global $wpdb` before it used.

Answer (score 1):

first you want to use your custom code in wordpress then you have to create custom template, save your php file in your theme folder with template name
for e.g

```
<?php
/* Template Name: login */
?>
<?php get_header();?>
<?php
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['userpass'];

$results = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare( 
"
    SELECT *
    FROM wp_users 
    WHERE user_login = %s
",
$name
),ARRAY_N,0);

$checked = wp_check_password($pass, $results[2]);

if ($checked) {
echo 'y';
} else {
echo 'n';
}
<?php get_footer();?>
```

now go to your wordpress dashboard and create page on righthand side select your created template name login from drop-down and save page.
after that run page which you have created with wordpress dashboard

Comment: Thank you. I will do so. However, this is not what I am asking. This php page is located in a separate folder in `public_html` folder. My question is how a php will return 404 with its contents (if it is due to WP, so how)? I have also wrote some other php files, but return 200.

Comment: @XiaojunChen Please provide full path where is your file and where is your header file because if you are not working in Wordpress folder then you can not use $wpdb object. if you want to use $wpdb object then you have to create file in WordPress theme folder as i explain above.

Comment: my file is in a folder called `myfolder` I created myself, `wp-blog-header.php` is located in `public_html`. Again, I used `$wpdb` and its method like `get_row`. It did return correct answer.